# In custom 'alert' or 'confirm' box remaining code get execute before press ok

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I had created two functions alert and confirm to override the alert and confirm box.

```
alert()
{
   $('#alertModal').modal('open');
}
confirm()
{
   $('#confirmModal').modal('open');
}
```

And calling it :

```
function Test()
{
   var x = confirm('are you confirm?');
   y = 11;
}
```

Normally `y=11` statement will not be executed unless an user select either of 'ok' or 'cancel' button press. But in my custom confirm `y=11` statement get execute before 'ok' or 'cancel' button press.

Comment: The "standard" `alert()` and `confirm()` modals are blocking, whereas yours is not. You have to add some callback function or promise pattern to react on the actual results.

Comment: I wrote a callback function. And it is giving me result as well i.e true or false. But the problem is with blocking. How to create blocking modal? can you show it fiddler.

Comment: @Sirko : How to show bootstrap modal like showmodaldialog?

Comment: Afaik you can not create a blocking modal on your own. JS by its nature is async, so it has almost no blocking methods. Wrt to bootstrap - i have no clue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for example jQuery UI to create confirm dialog, for example:

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete-file', function () {
        var data = $(this).data(),
            fileId = data.fileId;

        $('<div><p>Are you sure you wish to delete this file?</p></div>').dialog({
            title: 'Delete Confirmation',
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            draggable: false,
            closeOnEscape: true,
            buttons: [
                {
                    text: 'Yes',
                    click: function () {
                        // handle your stuff here
                        $(this).dialog('destroy');
                    }
                },
                {
                    text: 'No',
                    click: function () {
                        $(this).dialog('destroy');
                    }
                }]
        });
    });
```